# Android Code to connect MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I am creating android app where user sends some query to website which responses with the message.

PHP SCRIPT
`<?php echo $_REQUEST['q']; echo "welcome"; ?>`

and my android code

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView text1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);//textview initialization
    try {
         // Construct data
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("q", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("hello", "UTF-8");
        // Send data
        URL url = new URL("http://www.mysitename/query.php");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); //this line shows error in log
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
         StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        // Read in the data from the Buffer until nothing is left
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            theStringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        String result = theStringBuilder.toString();
        text1.setText(result); //Modifying the TextView
        wr.close();
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

While trying in emulator I get no response and my log has an error and layout shows Default `Hello World`

`at com.example.www.sendingdata.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)`

I searched couple of questions but they dont seem to help me. please help me solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this code to grab the remote data, this code always work with me:

```
                String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try{
        URL url = new URL("http://www.mysitename/query.php");
        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(7000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(7000);
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200 ){
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br;
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            //Log.d("data", data);
            br.close();
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

    }catch (IOException e) {

        data = "error";
    }
TextView text1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
text1.setText(data );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
out.write("INSERT INTO DATABASE_NAME (ROWS) VALUES (VALUES)".getBytes());
```

Comment: BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
I do like that with Sockets maybe is similar

Comment: no it does not work, shows type mismatch during build.

Comment: Ok i found the solution